# The contract between Crowley and Dick

Tags: supernatural

Spoilers ahead for Season 7 Finale:
After going through an extensive contract, the deal is struck between Crowley and Dick for Crowley to give the Winchesters the wrong blood.

> However since Dean is able to kill Dick later in the episode it must be assumed that Crowley gave them his blood. How was Crowley able to break the contract and give them his blood?

Comment: Hey, I think [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/27585) is the answer to your question. If it is, I will remove my incorrect answer. Let me know. :)

Comment: @IshitaSinha that does appear to deal with the question.  It would have been nice if there was a more concrete in universe explanation, especially after making such a big deal about writing the contract in the first place.

Comment: I know, right? :)